# How to implement furthest point Voronoi diagram in Python when several points have the same color?

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi

I'm trying to use `scipy.spatial.voronoi(points,furthest_site = True)` in Python3 to create a furthest point Voronoi diagram. However, the input of this function can only be points with different colors. What if I have several point with the same color and then use these sets of points to generate the diagram?

For example,when I have 8 input points:

```
points = []
for i in range(8):
    points.append((random.randint(0, 10000), random.randint(0, 10000)))
vor = Voronoi(points,furthest_site=True)
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
```

However, I want to generate figure like this: [figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkThW.jpg)

Comment: Hi. Can you provide an example of what our are trying to do. The documentation of `scipy.spatial.voronoi` make no mention of colors

Comment: Could you provide a more specific example of what you're getting vs. what you expect?